# How to "really" delete whatsapp images that were already deleted?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I've deleted around 800 images from WhatsApp folder using Google's `Photos` app, but the problem is no space was free'd at all, I'm guessing those images are still available at /sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images.

Is there a way to delete those 800 *"original photos"* without having to manually select them again?

I'm using Motorola Moto X Play, Android 6.0.1, no sd card at all.

PS: I have Google Photos backup disabled even before that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the pictures were actually totally removed, I didn't notice any significant space change because WhatsApp compress every image, so 800 pictures probably was less than 200MB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting all the images in the directory, just delete the directory. If not, unfortunately Google Photos is a backup and unless you have it enabled to delete backed up photos off your device, I don't believe there is a way to mirror the deletions.

Comment: I already have  Google Photos backup disabled before that happening, does that change anything?

Comment: @Edson if you deleted the photos on Google Photos then it would have been the backups most likely. When you were deleting the photos, did you press delete device copy?

Comment: Yes I did chose that option @MitchB

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior, have you verified that the files can still be accessed from within whatsapp? I deleted a few recent photos and received an error message that the media was not available on my device. After doing some digging in the backup settings, it does mention that the app makes local backups as well as cloud backups, perhaps this is why you see no space savings?

Comment: I just checked it, it's actually been totally removed. I guess I didn't noticed any significant space change because WhatsApp compress every image, so 800 pictures probably was less than 200MB. Thanks for your help! Should I erase the question?

Comment: If you mark it answered, other people can use it for reference in the future.